# react & node API - fetch function error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm just new in React and NodeJS express programming and I'm stuck in some error for hours.
when I'm trying to fetch, sometimes I got a response (but not the my response)
and sometimes I got 'failed to fetch'.

I have tried to understand 'cors' concept without a lot of understanding,
but I have commit app.use(cors()) that allowed every source.

note that my server sometimes got 'OPTIONS' request, and sometimes getting 'POST' request.

in my React, I have this function:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
        },
        body: JSON.stringify ({
          user: this.state.username,
          pass: this.state.password,
        })
      }).then(res => {
          console.log(res.msg);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        alert(err);
      })
}
```

in my NodeJS I have this function:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
let user = {
    username: req.body.user,
    password: req.body.pass 
}
UserModel.findOne({'username': user.username, 'password' : user.password}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'login failed, try later'
        });
    } else if (user) {
        let token = jwt.encode(user, secret);
        res.json({
            msg: 'logged in',
            ok: true
        });
    } else {
        res.json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'invalid input'
        });
    }
});
```

Im very confused, I hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your router prefixed with /api/login?

Comment: Yes, even though my server answered the requests (sometimes, not always, cant detect when.)

Comment: verify on the POST , server-side that u are actually getting  req.body.user&&.pass  because u may need to config the body/parser module that you want to consume POST.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't accessing the JSON of the response correctly. You need to call the [`Body#json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method of the response to actually access the JSON content. Also note that it returns a promise that resolves to the JSON content of a response:

```
fetch('…', { … })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json.msg);
  });
```

Also, I recommend sending an HTTP status code along with the JSON instead of having an `ok` property. That is a standard way and has builtin support through the `Response` object:

```
res.status(200).json({ … });
```